# Google Cloud Platform App Engine - installing a custom runtime

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cython

I'm using google app-engine (standard environment) in GCP with python2.7 interpreter.
I want to use a different python compiler. Specifically, I want to use cython [https://github.com/cython/cython][1]

Can I please know if app-engine (standard environment) can support custom runtimes ?

I understand that app-engine (flexible environment) can support custom runtimes with the
help of docker images.

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: Hopefully, someone can answer you but irrespective of the answer, you should be moving away from Python 2.7 on GAE since GAE is no longer actively supporting it (all new features are being built for Python 3 only)

Comment: Use Cloud Run. You can manage your runtime environment (your own container) and deploy it in a very similar way as app engine.